# Differential in Lagrangian description, missing term?

Tags: continuum-mechanics

First, let's consider some function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ as 
$$\mathbf{f}=\mathbf{f}(x_1,\,...,\,x_n)$$
Clearly, its differential is given by
$$d\mathbf{f}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial x_1}\,dx_1+...+\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial x_n}\,dx_n$$
Then for some function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ defined as
$$\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{\varphi}(\mathbf{X},t)$$
we have
$$d\mathbf{x}=\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial \mathbf{X}}\cdot d\mathbf{X}\,+\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial t}\,dt$$
But in Continuum Mechanics theory (See 'An Introduction to Continuum Mechanics, J.N. Reddy', or [Form for a material element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem#Form_for_a_material_element)), I find the following expression
$$d\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{F}\,\cdot d\mathbf{X}$$
where
$$\mathbf{F}\equiv\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \mathbf{X}}\,,\;\;\;\;\mathbf{x}\equiv\mathbf{\varphi}(\mathbf{X},t)$$

So what about temporal term? Shouldn't be included as well? Why is it eliminated?

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea that may explain the questioning.

Let's analize
$$d\mathbf{x}=\frac{\partial\varphi(\mathbf{X},t)}{\partial \mathbf{X}}\cdot d\mathbf{X}\,+\frac{\partial\varphi(\mathbf{X},t)}{\partial t}\,dt$$
which implicitely means
$$d\mathbf{x}=\left.\frac{\partial\varphi(\mathbf{X},t)}{\partial \mathbf{X}}\right|_{t_{REF}}\cdot\, d\mathbf{X}\,+\left.\frac{\partial\varphi(\mathbf{X},t)}{\partial t}\right|_{\mathbf{X}_{REF}}\,dt\;=\;\underset{d\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}{\underbrace{d\mathbf{x}\Big|_{t_{REF}}}}+\underset{ds}{\underbrace{d\mathbf{x}\Big|_{\mathbf{X}_{REF}}}}$$

- $d\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}\equiv d\mathbf{x}\Big|_{t_{REF}}\;\;$term represents the geometrical distance between two particles of material distance $d\mathbf{X}$, at a certain reference time $t_{REF}$ (note that material distance $d\mathbf{X}$ does not change with time, since it deforms with material, so it can be used as a convenient fixed reference for deformated distance $d\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$)
- $ds\equiv d\mathbf{x}\Big|_{\mathbf{X}_{REF}}\;\;$represents the space covered by the reference particle $\mathbf{X}_{REF}$ in a $dt$ of time

We can notice that the sum $d\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}+ds$ doesn't have physical meaning by itself, it's then convenient to treat the two cases separately. When we talk about deformations, we just need the $d\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$ term. For brevity, we just refer to it as $d\mathbf{x}$, thus the semplified expression: $$d\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{X}$$

Note: The same reasoning can be applied to the volume integral found in [Reynold's Transport theorem proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem#Form_for_a_material_element), whose change of variables is made possible by the fact that $dV$ corresponds to an infinitesimal volume at a certain time $t_{REF}$, thus only vector components of $d\mathbf{x}\Big|_{t_{REF}}$ have to be considered in order to evaluate $dV$ (the pedex in $d\mathbf{x}$ is then omitted for brevity).